# How to set the right Billing Tier in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Please let me know how to calculate and set the right billing tier in Google BigQuery.

I have built queries. Some of them will process 3 tables of each 50 GB and other queries process the tables of each 100-200 GB.

I don't prefer to run the smaller queries with high billing tier.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute), you don't actually set directly which billing tier you'll be running a query but rather you set the maximum tier you allow BigQuery to reach for finishing a given job.

As you can see in the [job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) resource definition, you can define for the `query` method the parameter [maximumBillingTier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBillingTier) that sets how much your costs can potentially rise for the query to complete successfully.

Still, keep in mind that many high-compute queries can be greatly  optimized by changing a few techniques in the query, such as using analytical functions, arrays and structs, subqueries and so on.

Given that you are working with relatively small data for BigQuery, you probably can find great ways to optimize your query and not have it processing as a high-computing query.

Comment: Thanks, Willian. The data in our table will grow every day. Due to cost limitations, we don't want to give high tier to all queries. We want to make a strict check on the tier and track it. If we are able to find the right tier then we can do better estimate and forecast on cost.